# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php, html

**Hello I have a problem when I connect via steam to my site it gives me its errors:**

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/boutique.sky-community.com/index.php on line 67
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/boutique.sky-community.com/index.php on line 68
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/boutique.sky-community.com/index.php on line 69
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/boutique.sky-community.com/index.php on line 70
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/boutique.sky-community.com/index.php on line 71
```

**Here is part of my index.php:**

```php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['gex_steamid64'])) {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['gex_loginsession'])) {
            $db->where('session', $_COOKIE['gex_loginsession']);
            $db->where('expires > NOW()');

            $steamid64 = $db->getValue('sessions', 'steamid64');

            if ($db->count) {
                $db->where('session', $_COOKIE['gex_loginsession']);
                $db->update('sessions', array('expires' => $db->func('DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY)', array(30))));

                $_SESSION['gex_steamid64'] = $steamid64;

                setcookie('gex_loginsession', $_COOKIE['gex_loginsession'], time() + 2592000, '/');
            }
        }
    } elseif (isset($_GET['login_started'])) {
        $steamprofile = SteamAPI::GetUserData($_SESSION['gex_steamid64']);

        $steamid32 = $steamprofile['steamid32'];
        $nick = $steamprofile['personaname'];
        $avatar_small = $steamprofile['avatar'];
        $avatar_medium = $steamprofile['avatarmedium'];
        $avatar_large = $steamprofile['avatarfull'];

        $db->where('steamid64', $_SESSION['gex_steamid64']);
        $userdata = $db->getOne('users');

        $ip = GetClientIP();
        $ips = array($ip);

        if ($db->count) {
            $sessionkey = hash('sha512', random_string(25).$userdata['random']); //(hash("sha256", md5('Ew97f9N3vq4' . $_SESSION['gex_steamid64'] . '86V' . $result['email'] . 'b93z7' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . '4E$HSJH8gjsA' . $result['random'] . '3oikjfA')));

            setcookie('gex_loginsession', $sessionkey, time() + 2592000, '/');
```

**Its only done when you log in and its not working, could anyone help me?**

Comment: `$steamprofile` is most likely false, which means `SteamAPI::GetUserData` couldn't get the user data.

Comment: Give us a hint, which line is line 67 of the 33 lines you show us :)

Comment: Okay, but how do I deal with the problem?

Comment: What line is it telling you is the problem? Says you're trying to reference an array index on a variable that isn't an array (it's a boolean).

Comment: Line 64 and this:

$steamid32 = $steamprofile['steamid32'];

Comment: Work out why `$steamprofile = SteamAPI::GetUserData($_SESSION['gex_steamid64']);` is not returning what you expect

Comment: I still don't understand the problem, here is line 67 to 17 :

$steamid32 = $steamprofile['steamid32'];
$nick = $steamprofile['personaname'];
$avatar_small = $steamprofile['avatar'];
$avatar_medium = $steamprofile['avatarmedium'];
$avatar_large = $steamprofile['avatarfull'];

Comment: So for some reason this line `$steamprofile = SteamAPI::GetUserData($_SESSION['gex_steamid64']);` most likely returned FALSE instead of the row of a table as an array

Comment: Line 67 : $ steamid32 = $ steamprofile ['steamid32'];

Comment: Basically, this `$steamprofile = SteamAPI::GetUserData($_SESSION['gex_steamid64']);` is returning false. Thats why when you try to access `$steamprofile` as an array its not, it's false (a boolean)

Comment: Okay, what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Figure out why it's returning false. Is `$_SESSION['gex_steamid64']` an actual ID, and is it a valid one?

Comment: Just before this line `$steamprofile = SteamAPI::GetUserData($_SESSION['gex_steamid64']);` do this `var_dump($_SESSION['gex_steamid64']);` what does it output? A valid steam id or null?

Comment: I added `var_dump ($ _ SESSION ['gex_steamid64']);` and its returned to me `string (17) "76561198401866399"` with my valid SteamID

Comment: I assume you're using this library https://github.com/Secco2112/SteamAPI ?

Comment: Surely I don't know, I use Gextension it's a CMS for garry's mod : https://www.gmodstore.com/market/view/gextension-the-all-in-one-package-for-your-community

Comment: So can someone help me?